# Ubuntu 14.04 VM setup using Virtual Box

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I am trying to create a Ubuntu 14.04 VM using VirtualBox. After reading the ISO, the VM completes copying the files and asks for a restart, then gets stuck at this message :

[image]

I have tried it twice, the VM never restarts.

My host machine is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

VirtualBox version is 4.3.10.

Can someone please suggest a way to solve this ?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

The complete message is as follows:

[image]

After waiting for a while, this screen changes to the first image, and then it just stays there forever.

**Edit 2:**

I tried with VirtualBox 4.2.24. I get a similar screen which gets stuck :

[image]

Comment: Could you please add the message in its entirety?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply eject installation CD and restart the VM

[image]

Comment: I am creating VM from an ISO file.

Comment: Hit button "Remove disk from virtual drive"?

Comment: Where is that option in VirtualBox menu ?

Answer (score 0):

The step that needed to be completed in the end was click 'remove disk from virtual drive', then press enter.

See image [here](http://wiki.rosalab.ru/en/images/d/d8/ROSA_Remove_Disk_en.png).